# Random test data generator basis specific fields

Tags: web-apps, software-testing, data

Can anyone suggest me a website that can generate random data with filters like State and city. I would like to have some test data for my application testing that needs, Name;Address;PhoneNo;Latitude;Longitude; for a specific city and state.

I couldn't find any such site exactly when i browsed online, what was close to was this https://www.mockaroo.com but it doesn't allow me to choose a specific state and city.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What real data do you want to use and what fake data do you want to generate? For example, do you want real longitudes and latitudes from the city in question while faking the rest, or do you want real addresses, longitudes, and latitudes while only faking names and phone numbers?